# Reactjs Audio button?

Tags: reactjs

In html I create a audio button by this code

```
<html><head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="http://pingendo.github.io/pingendo-bootstrap/themes/default/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head><body>
        <script>
        function aud_play_pause() {
            var myAudio = document.getElementById("myTune");
            if (myAudio.paused) {
                myAudio.play();
            } else {
                myAudio.pause();
            }
        }
        </script>
        <audio id="myTune">
            <source src="./audio/rain.mp3">
        </audio>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                   <a class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="button" onclick = "aud_play_pause()">Rain</a>
             </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

And it work but in reactjs I use three file below with same path with that html but code don't work like that, I get a blank website. Sorry for my bad english. 
index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://pingendo.github.io/pingendo-bootstrap/themes/default/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Test.js

```
var React = require('react');  

var Test = React.createClass( {  
        aud_play_pause() {
            var myAudio = document.getElementById("myTune");
            if (myAudio.paused) {
                myAudio.play();
            } else {
                myAudio.pause();
            }
        },
        render () {
            return(
               <div>
                    <audio id="myTune">
                        <source src="./audio/rain.mp3" />
                    </audio>
                    <div className="col-md-2">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-12">
                                <a className="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="button" onClick = {this.aud_play_pause()}>Rain</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
            );
        }
});
export default Test;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Test from './Test';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Test />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Update your onclick code like this. onClick = {this.aud_play_pause} remove brackets.

Comment: Try to use `react-bootstrap` instead of `btn btn-block ...` and so on...

Comment: Thanks, but that help me display button but it don't have audio when I click on it like only use html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onClick` in react expects a function . But when you do `onClick = {this.aud_play_pause()}`, it is returned a value . Change the onClick definition to

```
onClick = {this.aud_play_pause}
```

Code:

```
var React = require('react');  

var Test = React.createClass( {  
        aud_play_pause() {
            var myAudio = this.mytune;
            if (myAudio.paused) {
                myAudio.play();
            } else {
                myAudio.pause();
            }
        },
        render () {
            return(
               <div>
                    <audio id="myTune" ref = {(ip)=> {this.mytune = ip}}>
                        <source src={require("./audio/rain.mp3")}/>
                    </audio>
                    <div className="col-md-2">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-12">
                                <a className="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="button" onClick = {this.aud_play_pause}>Rain</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
            );
        }
});
export default Test;
```

You will also need a bundler for instance `webpack` to transpile your code.

See the setup example **[here](https://humaan.com/blog/getting-started-with-webpack-and-react-es6-style/)**:

Also if you use the latest version of `React` , you will get a warning that afte `v15.5.0` `React.createClass` will be deprecated and hence it will be better to start of with the `React.Component`

```
import React from 'react';  

class Test extends React.Component{

        aud_play_pause() {
            var myAudio = this.myTune;
            if (myAudio.paused) {
                myAudio.play();
            } else {
                myAudio.pause();
            }
        }
        render () {
            return(
               <div>
                    <audio id="myTune" ref={(ip) => {this.mytune = ip}}>
                        <source src={require("./audio/rain.mp3")} />
                    </audio>
                    <div className="col-md-2">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-12">
                                <a className="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="button" onClick = {this.aud_play_pause}>Rain</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
            );
        }
}
export default Test;
```

Comment: Thanks, but that help me display button but it don't have audio when I click on it like only use html. Btw IDM identified that audio before I click but not audio is playing

Comment: Wrap the audio src within the curly brackets. Updated the code. Also make use of ref callback to get access to the audio element which is the react way

Comment: Glad to have helped. Also as suggested you should migrate to the ES6 way of writing React components

Answer (score 0):

Update your Test.js like below.

```
var React = require('react');  

var Test = React.createClass( {  
        aud_play_pause: function() {
            var myAudio = document.getElementById("myTune");
            if (myAudio.paused) {
                myAudio.play();
            } else {
                myAudio.pause();
            }
        },
        render: function() {
            return(
               <div>
                    <audio id="myTune">
                        <source src="./audio/rain.mp3" />
                    </audio>
                    <div className="col-md-2">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-12">
                                <a className="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="button" onClick = {this.aud_play_pause}>Rain</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
            );
        }
});
export default Test;
```

Comment: Thanks, but that help me display button but it don't have audio when I click on it like only use html

Comment: Yep. IDM identified that audio before I click but not audio is playing before or after I click on it

Comment: disable your IDM extension in your browsers.