# Cannot pass a function to child component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know why but I cannot set an onClick function for a function from the parent that I want to pass to my child component. This is the code from the parent:

```
_renderChatFriend() {
    return([...this.state.friendsNames].map( friend => {
      return (<ChatFriendPopUp 
          onChatFriendPopUpClick={this.popUpMessage} 
          key={friend.id} 
          name={friend.name} 
        />)
    }))
  }
```

and the code on the child component:

```
class ChatFriendPopUp extends Component {
  popUpMessage(name) {
    console.log("name clicked ",name)
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <li  onClick={this.props.onChatFriendPopUpClick(this.props.name)}>{this.props.name}</li>
    )
  }
}
```

The onClick is invoked upon mount? and when I click it's not invoked? but I can invoke it by onClick if I don't pass an argument on it. A code like this but I cannot have referrence:

```
<li  onClick={this.props.onChatFriendPopUpClick}> // not passing argument works?
```

Comment: You're calling it-not sure what you expect. Are you actually asking how to use it but pass a parameter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reactjs Audio button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43359992/reactjs-audio-button)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add it as a callback function otherwise it will get called immediately. Change it to this

```
 <li onClick={() => this.props.onChatFriendPopUpClick(this.props.name)}>{this.props.name}</li>
```

Comment: do you have some links so I can read more on this? it works but I feel like missing something

Comment: @iamnewbie The React Tutorials are a nice start, but that one is JavaScript specific. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html